# Section/Topic segmentation in HTML and plaintext documents

Tags: nlp, text-mining, text

GROBID (https://github.com/kermitt2/grobid) is terrific for fine-grained (section, chapter) segmentation of PDF files, but I need to do the equivalent for HTML and plaintext files.

I've tried TextTiling but it seems to work only for coarse-grained topic change detection (like distinguishing between newspaper articles regarding very different subjects).

What are methods and/or SW toolkits that I could use to segment a document into sections regarding particular fine-grained topics?